# There is an issue with Publishing the changes for a page

Tags: azure, kentico

We tried to publish the changes after editting.

But it shows an error about Out Of Memory Exception with checking in Event Log.

Any adivices about this issue.

Hosting: Azure 
Kentico: 10.0.50

[image: Event Log]

Comment: Have you tried increasing memory of the azure app? Or maybe restart of the app will help in case the memory is full or you have memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Kentico's [hosting requirements](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/server-and-hosting-requirements) state you need a minimum of at least 4GB of RAM but 8GB is recommended.  If you have caching enabled and cache pretty heavy, your 4GB of memory will be eaten up very quickly.  I'd suggest increasing your App Service to at least an S2 if not an S3 and see if this resolves the issue.

If you continue to see errors like this, enable [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) on the website to help with monitoring and getting a deeper look into what may be causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am using S2 for the site now. Right now, it is working well after I restarted application. 

I think it will happen again if there are many requests. So S3 can solve the issue, right?

Comment: Simply throwing resources at a website doesn't provide a long term solution.  I suggest finding out what the underlying issue is by using Application Insights and debugging your code.